# Do DNS Servers Enable Secure Cache Against Pollution setting by Default?

Tags: domain-name-system

Do most DNS Resolver servers enable cache pollution protection (by default, or during set up), like the setting Microsoft DNS Server has?

"Secure Cache Against Pollution setting" After you enable this setting, the DNS server ignores DNS resource records that come from servers that are not authoritative for them. Although it can cause extra DNS queries, the security benefits far outweigh the cost of the extra queries, so enabling DNS cache pollution protection is highly recommended.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316786

I am noticing very slow times with it on, and I am not sure what everyone else is doing about it!

Answer (score 0):

The newest versions of software generally have the option, but not enabled by default, everything else no.

I personally don't worry about DNS Cache Pollution, authority is easy to fake if your upstream dns server has been rooted. Cache Poisoning is hard to defend against, and is a large reason behind the push for DNSSEC.

Answer (score 0):

Windows DNS does have this on by default.